# Wampserver restarts Automatically

Tags: php, wampserver, restart

I am developing a PHP script that executes for about 5 hours, but the problem is that WampServer automatically restarts that stops the script.
How can I prevent WampServer to restart automatically?

Comment: It doesn't restart automatically, unless something is crashing the server.

Comment: I don't user Windows so am unaware if WAMP has any built in functionality for automaticall restarting.  However, have you checked any log files to see if there's a message as to why it's restarting?

Comment: What is your allowed maximal execution time?
See http://www.php.net/manual/de/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time for configuration.

Comment: max_execution_time = 1000000

Comment: i'll see the log files, thank you

Comment: There i snithing in WAMPServer that would automatically restart apahe. If you have a PHP script that runs for 5 Hours it really ought to be using PHP CLI and not the webserver interface. Also there is no execution time limit when using the CLI.